# /bin/systemctl: No such file or directory

Tags: rhel, systemd

I am trying to update a software system running on RedHat Enterprise Server 6.8, however it failed.

In the log file there is a message:

```
Running: "/bin/systemctl is-active postgresql-qrd.service"
sh: /bin/systemctl: No such file or directory
```

Can anybody give me pointer why we have that error? I cannot find `systemctl` in the file system.

Comment: You have showed an error message, but you don't even mention what command it is that produces this.

Answer (score 2):

RHEL6 doesn't use systemd, follow RHEL6 documentation on [managing system services](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-Services_and_Daemons.html)